# Inquiry About Installation Problems of "LIGGGHTS" software in Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04

I am facing the following problem when I am trying to install 'LIGGGHTS' software using 'make auto' in Ubuntu. I got the following error. May I please know where is the problem?

```
Creating list of contact models completed.
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/slm_lab/LIGGGHTS-PUBLIC/src/Obj_auto'
mpicxx -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing -Wall -Wno-unused-result -O2  -std=c++17 -fPIC    -I/usr/include/vtk-7.1 -DLAMMPS_VTK -DSUPERQUADRIC_ACTIVE_FLAG -DNONSPHERICAL_ACTIVE_FLAG   -c ../compute_pair_gran_local.cpp
In file included from ../granular_pair_style.h:47,
                 from ../pair_gran_proxy.h:58,
                 from ../compute_pair_gran_local.cpp:50:
../utils.h: In function ‘std::string LIGGGHTS::Utils::int_to_string(int)’:
../utils.h:70:12: error: invalid ‘static_cast’ from type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char>’ to type ‘std::ostringstream&’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char>&’}
   70 |     return static_cast< std::ostringstream & >(( std::ostringstream() << std::dec << a ) ).str();
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1399: compute_pair_gran_local.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/slm_lab/LIGGGHTS-PUBLIC/src/Obj_auto'
make: *** [Makefile:114: auto] Error 2
```

Looking for some viable solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to install `liggghts` this package is available from the Ubuntu Universe repository using the standard package manager. Run the following commands to install using this method:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install liggghts
```

This will install version 3.8.0 which appears to be the same as the main branch on the github page.

<sub>Note: if you get a "package not found" error, run the following command to enable the Universe repository and then try again:</sub>

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

---

If for some reason you absolutely need to build this from source (if you are altering the source code or simply for educational purposes), you will most likely need to run the following commands to install the necessary build dependencies:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt build-dep liggghts
```

Before you run `make` again, be sure to run

```
make clean
```

I didn't even look into the error because 9/10, installing the build dependencies fixes the issue.

Comment: I tried to follow your steps. But I am still unable to run LIGGGHTS. I am following these steps.

Comment: sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo apt install openmpi-bin
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/CFDEMproject/LIGGGHTS-PUBLIC.git

Comment: sudo apt install cmake libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libboost-dev
libdouble-conversion-dev libeigen3-dev libexpat1-dev libfontconfig-dev libfreetype6-dev
libgdal-dev libglew-dev libhdf5-dev libjpeg-dev libjsoncpp-dev liblz4-dev liblzma-dev
libnetcdf-dev libnetcdf-cxx-legacy-dev libogg-dev libpng-dev libpython3-dev
libqt5opengl5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libsqlite3-dev libswscale-dev libtheora-dev
libtiff-dev libxml2-dev libxt-dev qtbase5-dev qttools5-dev zlib1g-dev

Comment: cd ~/LIGGGHTS-PUBLIC/src
make auto

Comment: But the "make auto" command actually rising the mentioned error in the 'question'.

Comment: @YeasirMohammadAkib Is there a reason you don't want to use the version from the official repository? `sudo apt install liggghts`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I am trying to install it with python from the official repository.